# Copy image from site to system clipboard with JS?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Is it some solution to copy image to system clipboard without Flash?
App is written in pure JS.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)